# problems when I try to run the neural network from github

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run the following github project:
https://github.com/jeffgreenca/laughr

I can run the command: `pipenv run python laughr.py --help`

but when I ask to mute a laugh from an audio file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "laughr.py", line 292, in <module>
    model=localModel)
  File "laughr.py", line 202, in do_mute_laughs
    laughr.remove_laughs(sourceFile, outFile)
  File "laughr.py", line 147, in remove_laughs
    rc.laughs = self.model.predict(rc.build_features())
  File "laughr.py", line 73, in build_features
    self.raw = self.y.T[0][i * chunkLen:(i + 1) * chunkLen]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I think it may be a wrong version of the tensorflow or keras that I am using, but I have no idea which one is right. thanks for listening.

Comment: check the repo's requirements.txt file if it exists.

Comment: He uses pipenv to install the dependencies, and Pipfile does not have versions provided, follows the Pipfile:

https://github.com/jeffgreenca/laughr/blob/master/src/Pipfile

thanks for try help!

Comment: I just found out that it was my audio that was broken...